# How can I get my divs more responsive for phones?

Tags: html, css, responsive

How can I get my "Meet our staff" page more responsive for phones? It's not looking good, having the items all the way to the left with lot of content left to use in the right spot.

I haven't tried much, as I really don't know what I can do.

Codepen here:https://codepen.io/audn/pen/EvNMvO?editors=1100

CSS:

```
    .bg-white{
  background-color:white;
  height: 216px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 180px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-right:20px;
  float:left;
}
.username{
  color:black;
  font-weight:900;
 }
.workspace{
  font-size:11px;
  color:#999;
}
.contact{
  background-color:#1798e5;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-top:12px;
  color:White;
  border-radius: .3em;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  font-size:13px;
  text-align:center;
}
.icons{
  font-size:16px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.contact:hover{
  background-color:#1765e5;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.avatar1{
  border-radius:999px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  position:relative;
  border: 5px solid white;
  width:90px;
  height:90px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="bg-white">
  <center>
  <img src="http://cdn.edgecast.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/68/68d720a786c605ff0cc4d80f10a4c2d6410bb2fc_full.jpg" class="avatar1">
  <div class="username">
    audunrp <i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#5EA5E7;"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="workspace">
     Administrator
    </div>
    <div class="contact" data-target="#audn-contact" data-toggle="modal">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> Message
      </div>
  </center>
</div>
<!--
audn
--><div class="bg-white">
  <center>
  <img src="http://cdn.edgecast.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/68/68d720a786c605ff0cc4d80f10a4c2d6410bb2fc_full.jpg" class="avatar1">
  <div class="username">
    audunrp <i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#5EA5E7;"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="workspace">
     Administrator
    </div>
    <div class="contact" data-target="#audn-contact" data-toggle="modal">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> Message
      </div>
  </center>
</div>
<!--
audn
--><div class="bg-white">
  <center>
  <img src="http://cdn.edgecast.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/68/68d720a786c605ff0cc4d80f10a4c2d6410bb2fc_full.jpg" class="avatar1">
  <div class="username">
    audunrp <i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#5EA5E7;"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="workspace">
     Administrator
    </div>
    <div class="contact" data-target="#audn-contact" data-toggle="modal">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> Message
      </div>
  </center>
</div>
<!--
audn
-->
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can use media-queries for make your html more responsive. Use the width of screen for resize your "bg-white", like "margin-left: 10%; width: 90%", when load site in phones (you set the size of screen in css)

Look more here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 1):

Using flex.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/pandalism1/pen/EvZKXm

**JS Fiddle**

```css
@media (max-width: 400px){
.bg-white {
    width: 100% !important;
}
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.bg-white{
  background-color:white;
  height: 216px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}
.username{
  color:black;
  font-weight:900;
 }
.workspace{
  font-size:11px;
  color:#999;
}
.contact{
  background-color:#1798e5;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-top:12px;
  color:White;
  border-radius: .3em;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  font-size:13px;
  text-align:center;
}
.icons{
  font-size:16px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.contact:hover{
  background-color:#1765e5;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.avatar1{
  border-radius:999px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  position:relative;
  border: 5px solid white;
  width:90px;
  height:90px;
}
```

```html
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="bg-white">
  <center>
  <img src="http://cdn.edgecast.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/68/68d720a786c605ff0cc4d80f10a4c2d6410bb2fc_full.jpg" class="avatar1">
  <div class="username">
    audunrp <i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#5EA5E7;"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="workspace">
     Administrator
    </div>
    <div class="contact" data-target="#audn-contact" data-toggle="modal">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> Message
      </div>
  </center>
</div>
  <div class="bg-white">
  <center>
  <img src="http://cdn.edgecast.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/68/68d720a786c605ff0cc4d80f10a4c2d6410bb2fc_full.jpg" class="avatar1">
  <div class="username">
    audunrp <i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#5EA5E7;"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="workspace">
     Administrator
    </div>
    <div class="contact" data-target="#audn-contact" data-toggle="modal">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> Message
      </div>
  </center>
</div>
  <div class="bg-white">
  <center>
  <img src="http://cdn.edgecast.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/68/68d720a786c605ff0cc4d80f10a4c2d6410bb2fc_full.jpg" class="avatar1">
  <div class="username">
    audunrp <i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#5EA5E7;"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="workspace">
     Administrator
    </div>
    <div class="contact" data-target="#audn-contact" data-toggle="modal">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> Message
      </div>
  </center>
</div>
  <div class="bg-white">
  <center>
  <img src="http://cdn.edgecast.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/68/68d720a786c605ff0cc4d80f10a4c2d6410bb2fc_full.jpg" class="avatar1">
  <div class="username">
    audunrp <i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#5EA5E7;"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="workspace">
     Administrator
    </div>
    <div class="contact" data-target="#audn-contact" data-toggle="modal">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> Message
      </div>
  </center>
</div>
  <div class="bg-white">
  <center>
  <img src="http://cdn.edgecast.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/68/68d720a786c605ff0cc4d80f10a4c2d6410bb2fc_full.jpg" class="avatar1">
  <div class="username">
    audunrp <i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#5EA5E7;"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="workspace">
     Administrator
    </div>
    <div class="contact" data-target="#audn-contact" data-toggle="modal">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> Message
      </div>
  </center>
</div>
  <div class="bg-white">
  <center>
  <img src="http://cdn.edgecast.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/68/68d720a786c605ff0cc4d80f10a4c2d6410bb2fc_full.jpg" class="avatar1">
  <div class="username">
    audunrp <i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#5EA5E7;"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="workspace">
     Administrator
    </div>
    <div class="contact" data-target="#audn-contact" data-toggle="modal">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> Message
      </div>
  </center>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a wrapper element, say a section, around the 3 divs with a class of bg-white. Add a style of text-align: center to center the 3 .bg-white divs within their section container.

Then, add a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) that will allow you to style the .bg-white divs at a certain screen/device width. Let's choose an arbitrary width of 640px.

At this break point, you can change the width of the .bg-white divs from their original width of 180px to 100% and make them display: block instead of display: inline-block so that they take up the entire width of the page and each will sit on it's own line.

These are the CSS changes you'd need to make this work.

```
.bg-white {
  background-color:white;
  height: 216px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 180px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-right:20px;
  /* float: left; */
 }

section {
  text-align: center;
}

/* place at the bottom of your CSS file, after all other rules */
@media (max-width: 640px) 
{
  .bg-white {
    width: 100%; 
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Don't forget to wrap your 3 .bg-white divs in a section container so that you can center them within this parent container.

These changes will give you 3 .bg-white divs that are centered within their parent container when your users view your site on their computers/laptops, and will show the same markup but with different, mobile optimized styles on mobile devices (because of the media query styles getting picked up when device width <= 640px).

Screenshots of what these added CSS rules and the addition of the section container would do for you.

Desktop
[image: Desktop]

Mobile
[image]

Comment: Remove float: left from .bg-white. Also, the media query needs to come after your other CSS rules. Updating answer.

Comment: You want to add the media query after your other CSS rules so the browser will read and interpret the rules within the query last, assuming the query's condition(s) are met. You'd typically want to add those at the very bottom of a given stylesheet.